I want to adjust the size of a Content View to fill the screen?

This is the .xib file
I can't edit the size of the contentView. When I play a video in the View, I want only 1 video to be played in the Content View and that video will fill the screen.
I'm new to swift code,
I'm trying to make a video running in tableview and want you to show me how to fix and add other ways to solve this problem. Thank you for reading my question and looking forward to receiving your help.

In the table view delegate methods set its height as its parent view controller.
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.frame.height
    }
}

And make sure that table view's constraints are (0,0,0,0) with ViewController. In other words make sure table view fills the ViewController.
